# What does it mean "no access to either C library or standard C headers"?

Tags: linux-kernel

Recently, I am reading a book called **Linux Kernel Development**, written by **Robert Love**.
In the second chapter, he states that

> the kernel has access to neither the C library nor the standard C
> headers.

As a newbie, I would like to ask how they wrote all the kernel without accessing standard files or the C library? Is it a common behavior while developing operating systems? Enlighten me, please

Answer (score 1):

The C library relies on the kernel for many of its functions; if the kernel were to try to use the C library, you’d end up with a loop. The standard C headers are provided by the C library and can’t be used either. The only libraries which *could* be used in a kernel are libraries with no external dependencies of their own, including to the C library (which means no memory allocations, no I/O...).

Kernels in general are developed by writing all the required code (perhaps copying it from a suitably-licensed library, in some cases). If you want to see what that looks like, the source code for very early versions of the Linux kernel is still available — see [version 0.01](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/Linux-0.01/sources/system/kernel/linux-0.01.tar.gz) for example.

Things have evolved somewhat since then, and the Linux kernel now has [its own “libraries”](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib) (modules of kernel code designed for re-use), and implementations of many C library-style routines (such as [the string manipulation functions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.6/source/lib/string.c)). It has its own [extensive headers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux) too. Even with all that though, writing modern C in the Linux kernel is quite different to writing modern C elsewhere...

Comment: I see many things ahead to learn. Thanks for your kind answer, sir :)

Answer (score 0):

It will use other libraries. It can not use the standard libraries, the ones that cause system-calls into the kernel. It is the kernel.

Therefore there are other libraries. This should be explained in the book.

Comment: There are other libraries? Which ones?

Comment: @StephenKitt I am assuming that there are kernel libraries. See the answer from Stephen kitt, where there seems to be a help full link. My answer was based on more general experience (I have done kernel and embedded programming, but in by 29 years of Gnu/Linux usage I have not (as far as I can remember) written any code for the kernel named Linux ).

Comment: Oh, given the way you wrote it I was under the impression you knew, and were being laconic. I thought it was worth expanding upon.